# Declaring variables before call to super() but super must be the first statement

Tags: java, constructor

I have a constructor in an abstract class that takes many parameters in it's constructor

I am trying to extend this class and I want to set some default values in the call to super() in the extended constructor.

The problem is that by looking at the code it looks messy seeing:

```
super(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
```

(bearing in mind this is simplified for stack overflow).

What I want to do is have the constructor like this:

```
    public Test(){
    int a = 0;
    int b = 1;
    int c = 2;
    int d = 3;
    int e = 4;
    int f = 5;
    int g = 6;
    int h = 7;
    int i = 8;
    int j = 9;
    super(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j);
}
```

Purely for visual and ease of reading purposes. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Can you not set all these variables as class members instead? Or must they be method specific?

Comment: `super(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);` is not messy at all. But looks like parent's constructor can be improved.

Comment: Sometimes this many arguments is an indicator that you many be violating the Single Responsibility Principle. If that's not the case, maybe a refactor using a factory or builder class is in order to clean this up.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not my Class to change so I can't change the parent's constructor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't do that - but if the important part is to give the arguments meaningful names, you could consider something like:

```
class Foo extends Bar {
    private static final int DEFAULT_WIDTH = 10;
    private static final int DEFAULT_HEIGHT = 10;

    public Foo() {
        super(DEFAULT_WIDTH, DEFAULT_HEIGHT);
    }
}
```

Personally I'd find that more self-explanatory than having local variables within the constructor anyway.

Another option for explanation is comments:

```
public Foo() {
    super(
        10,  // width
        10); // height
}
```

That's only going to be the same number of *lines* as your "declare separate variables" code anyway.

Comment: I think separating the variables with comments is the only real way to do it.

It's useful to know what the variable and the data type is so i've put that in a comment next to each one :) .

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't. The call to `super` must be the first line of the constructor.
You could define those default values as static final members of your class, though.

```
static final int a = 0;
static final int b = 1;
static final int c = 2;
static final int d = 3;
static final int e = 4;
static final int f = 5;
static final int g = 6;
static final int h = 7;
static final int i = 8;
static final int j = 9;

public Test()
{
    super(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can move the variables outside the Constructor

```
public class Test extends YourFancySuperclassWithToManyParametersInConstructor {
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0; 
    ...
    public Test() {
          super(a,b,...);
    }
}
```

Comment: Then they're fields though - and there's no indication that the OP *wants* those extra fields.

Answer (score 0):

The Java convention for declaring constants is to use 'final static' variables, so I suppose you could do that:

```
public class Y extends X {
    private static final int p1 = 1;
    private static final int p2 = 1;
    private static final int p3 = 1;

    public Y() {
        super(p1, p2, p3);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there are better ways to set the super class' values, but if you need to calculate variables before calling super, the only way I know is to do that in static methods and writing the calls of that methods in the argument list of the super call.
For example:

```
 class MySuper {
    int i1;
    int i2;
    int i3;
    public MySuper(int i, int ii, int iii){
        i1 = i;
        i2 = ii;
        i3 = iii;
    }
}

class MyClass extends MySuper {
    public MyClass() {
        super(calc1(), calc2(), calc3());
    }

    private static int calc1() {
        return 1;
    }
    private static int calc2() {
        return 2;
    }
    private static int calc3() {
        return 3;
    }
}
```

But if you only need constants, than the other answers are better.